# How to get the internal storage Directory such as "\flash"、"\emmc"

Tags: android, directory, storage, internal

External memory card can be read by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () to get an external memory card space. So how to get to the internal storage path? such as "/flash","/emmc",it is used as same as ExternalStorage, please help!

Answer (score 3):

you can get internal storage path by context.getCacheDir().and you can make file like below.
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"tempfile");

Comment: +1, navigated to this answer and it gave me a brilliant idea to solve an issue in my app!!